# Azure WebRole Sticky Load Balance

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I have an Azure WebRole, which publishes a WCF Service with PerSession setting. This means, session needs to be preserved for a long time... This is because of synch-framework and cannot be changed.

Now I have the problem when I want to use Multi-Instances on that Web Role (Classic Azure Cloud Service)

Can I configure an Application Gateway with endpoints not to the Public WebRole but to each Instances, so that the Gateway handles the Balancing?
How?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the [Application Gateway support for multi-tenant backends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-web-app-overview), you could configure an IP address or FQDN of your instances in the backends. Here is a quickstart: [Direct web traffic with Azure Application Gateway - Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/quick-create-portal)

However, the Application Gateway is known as application layer (OSI layer 7) load balancing which enables you to manage traffic to your web applications. Perhaps the traditional layer 4 load balancer is better for balancing WCF Service. Moreover, In Cloud Services, you get a load balancer automatically configured when you create the service. You could get more explanation in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473906/trying-to-understand-load-balancing-in-azure-cloud-sevice).

Ref: [Get started creating an internal load balancer (classic) for cloud services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-classic-cloud)