# Azure Access an ILB from Internet

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-application-gateway

I've already asked how to create a Loadbalancer with IP Affinity on Azure Cloud services here:
[Azure WebRole Sticky Load Balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867544/azure-webrole-sticky-load-balance)

The problem is, that when creating an ILB, this ILB is not accessible from public. What is the correct approach to make the ILB publicly acessible?
I wan't to have a domain e.g. service.azurecloudapp.net and when Accessing it it should route me to the ILB which again balances the load to the instances depending on the client IP.

Unfortunately I cannot use application gateways on azure, because they don't seem to support classic virtual networks.. :-(

Any help highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I think I was thinking too far... Apparently, the default load balancer of a webrole already supports some kind of session affinity without changing any settings.
The only thing I did was to add the loadBalancerDistribution property.

```
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="cert" loadBalancerDistribution="sourceIP" />
```

Now it seems to work as expected.